# How to achieve multiple Active (read and write) sites(datacenters) with continuos datareplication using SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, replication, cluster-computing

I need SQL to be running on 2 data centers(DC) active/active.
There are tonnes of challanges to be done here and below are my requirements.

1. Data synchronization must be async. (For higher performance)
2. I need to be able to read/write on both DC
3. When Site1 goes down, all the traffic will be routed to Site2 and when Site1 comes back live, traffic will be shared again. In this case, data must sync back within 1-2 hours (based on down time obviously)
4. SQL Transactional replication or other SQL replications seems not a good option because of the following.
   a. If replication breaks, building back the replication will require 500GB to be transferred to the other Site.
   b. We need to break the repl sometimes to make changes such as adding new tables or changing primary keys.
   c. Sometimes for what ever the reason, that replication breaks by itself and even MS cannot find solution to that.
   d. I am not sure if peer to peer replication will resolve this.
   e. Merge replication seems scary and we don't know its implications that much and we don't want to carry extra GUIDs.
5. Today it will be 2 DCs but tomorrow we will add some more DCs and with possibility having one in Europe and one in Asia.
6. Desirable latency in replication is MAX 15 mins.
7. Most of all, I need a solution without a headache or with minimal.
8. We are getting EMC recovery point but that does not help me in ACTIVE/ACTIVE scenario as it is only DR.
9. I've evaluated the following productions and none provide me workable DB on the other end.

I will appreciate your help on this issue.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only active/active option for SQL Server is replication.  There is no other active/active option for SQL Server as of this writing.